# Problem with close/reopen policy

Tags: discussion

I ran into a problem today when I tried to vote to close a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27848/). The question had been perviously closed and I had voted for that closing, but now it had been reopened by a moderator. I thought it should still be closed since the only problem was a typo in the code. I found I could not make a vote to close because "You have already voted to close this question". Is this the policy? Can one not vote to close a reopened question if one has voted in the first closing?

Comment: This is intended behavior.  See this MSO question:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106692

Comment: Similarly, you only get one vote to reopen. This restriction is in place so that a select group of people don't repeatedly close/reopen certain questions if they've been overriden by the community/moderator. We haven't had a _need_ for this restriction, but on Stack Overflow and similar large sites, some closures are highly contentious, resulting in multiple close-reopen cycles (even with this rule!) and things would be worse without it.

Comment: I find this restriction rather silly in case the question has been reopened at OP's request and then clarified by an edit which makes clear that it should be closed for a different reason. Especially if we are going to "on hold" questions rather than close them, there seems to be a tacit expectation that questions will change significantly in the close/reopen process. Even if certain people choose to make a nuisance of themselves on some sites, I don't see how completely changing the rules of the game SE-wide is an appropriate mitigation.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The rules haven't changed... rather, these _were_ the rules since the early days of Stack Overflow. We just happen to not have had very many close → reopen → close scenarios on this site. Factor in the # of active close voters and among those, users that would've felt strongly enough to close again, you'll end up with a very small number of people who would've encountered this restriction in practice. In such cases, just use a moderator flag (use the "other" option to explain) or ping us or share a link in chat and canvass for close votes from eligible users.